# Fragment wont change other fragments background color

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner that has different color options. I want to have the top half only include the spinner, and the bottom half to change the color of its background to the color selected from the spinner. 
Ex: blue selected from spinner
Bottom half display: Color blue as the background and have the text blue display

I have created a bundle in **PaletteFragment (which includes the spinner)** that uses `setArguments()` to pass the position clicked to **CanvasFragment (which should change the color background with the appropriate position it receives)**

Having trouble seeing why it's not changing the bottom layouts background color because I get no errors in Logcat even when I select a color from the spinner.

PaletteFragment:

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PaletteFragment #newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PaletteFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public static PaletteFragment newIntance(){
        return new PaletteFragment();
    }
    public PaletteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PaletteFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PaletteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PaletteFragment fragment = new PaletteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity(), R.array.myColors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringNames = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stringNames.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringName = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stringName.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette,container,false);
        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(new ColorAdapter(getActivity()));

        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ViewGroup container;
                if(position == 0){
                }
                else if(position == 1){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 2){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 3){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 4){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 5){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 6){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 7){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 8){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 9){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }else if(position == 10){
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

CanvasActivity:

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link CanvasFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link CanvasFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class CanvasFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public CanvasFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment CanvasFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CanvasFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CanvasFragment fragment = new CanvasFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_canvas, container, false);
        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newColor);
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.secondLayout);
        final View newBackground;
        fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        int pos = b.getInt("position");
        if(pos == 1){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.silver);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 2){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.pink);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 3){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 4){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 5){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 6){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 7){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 8){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.indigo);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 9){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.violet);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }else if(pos == 10){
            fragment.getView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.brown);
            if(CurrentLang=="es"){
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }else{
                displayColorName(pos,text);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
    private void displayColorName(int pos, TextView text){
        String retrieve[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
        String color = retrieve[pos];
        text.setText(color);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

CanvasActivity:

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CanvasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas);
        CanvasFragment CanvasFragment = new CanvasFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.secondLayout,CanvasFragment,CanvasFragment.getTag())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

PaletteActivity:

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import java.util.Locale;


public class PaletteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PaletteFragment PaletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstLayout,PaletteFragment,PaletteFragment.getTag())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

ColorAdapter:

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ColorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Integer> colors;
    Context context;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context){

        this.context=context;
        colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int retrieve []=context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.myColors);
        for(int i:retrieve)
        {
            colors.add(i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return colors.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int args) {
        return colors.get(args);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int args) {
        return args;
    }

    public String getElementFromColors(int position){
        String CurrentLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        if(CurrentLang.equals("es")){
            String retrieve[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
            return retrieve[position];
        }else{

            String retrieve[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStrings);
            return retrieve[position];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setBackgroundColor(colors.get(position));
        txv.setText(getElementFromColors(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

[image]

Top half includes the spinner dropdown only

Once I select a color, I want to have the bottom half change the background of that layout to that selected color

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem:**

Your code creates a `CanvasFragment` for each selection of an item in the spinner *but does nothing with it*. **A fragment must be added to a `FragmentManager` to be visible!**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ViewGroup container;
                if(position == 0){
                }
                else if(position == 1){

                    // New fragment is created, arguments are set, and then ... nothing.
                    // That's it. It's just left hanging.
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt("position",position);
                    CanvasFragment newFragment = new CanvasFragment();
                    newFragment.setArguments(args);

             // MORE CODE LIKE THIS
```

**Your Solution:**

You have to update your code so the `PaletteFragment` *notifies* the `CanvasActivity` that a new selection was made and then have it *update* the current `CanvasFragment`.

You should have *one* activity that owns both Fragments.
Your activity should implement an interface that gets invoked when a color is picked.
The `PaletteFragment` should access its Activity, cast it to the interface type, and invoke the method on it to notify that a selection was made.
In the Activity, the interface method should then update the currently selected color on the `CanvasFragment` based on the argument given.

Hope that helps!

[See the documentation for details on communicating between fragments.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)